# grub menu resolution problem on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, grub2

When I cold boot Ubuntu 12.10, the Grub menu font is stretched and the background doesn't cover the entire screen, like it's 640x800 resolution. If I reboot the grub menu is perfect, no font or size problems. I suspect I need to make some grub settings.  I did not have this problem with Ubuntu 12.04. Also I did an upgrade not a fresh install. I've played with grub customizer and video drivers, to no avail.

Comment: you mean , everytime with a restart you'll get proper grub menu & not in the 1st time power on ?